# Bicep Region Pairs

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

For Azure Bicep:

Given an array of region names `['eastus','westeurope','westus']`, how can I produce an array of unique region pairs?

i.e.: `[{ A:'eastus', B:'westeurope' },{ A:'westeurope', B:'westus' },{ A:'westus', B:'eastus' }]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [range function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-array#range) creates an array of integers that begins at the start index and contains the number of specified elements as detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/loops#loop-syntax).

Below code generates an array of objects with two properties, `A and B`.

A: - Represents the current region in an array,
and

B: - Represents the next region in an array.

```bash
param regionlist array = ['eastus','westeurope','westus']
var regionpairs = [
  for i in range(0, length(regionlist)): {
    A: regionlist[i]
    B: regionlist[(i + 1) % length(regionlist)]
  }
]
output regionpairs array = regionpairs
```

***Deployment:***

```bash
az bicep build --file array.bicep
az deployment group create --resource-group "xxxx" --template-file array.bicep
```

[image]